# If $F$ is a field then $F[\sqrt{-d}]$ is always a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $F$ is a field then $F[\sqrt{-d}]$ is always a field ?

I was taking $d=2$  as $F[\sqrt{-2}]$ is Euclidean domain. If I take $d=3,4,5\ldots$, what will be the result? Will they form a field or not? Or  will they always form a field for every $d=1,2,3,4,\ldots$?

Comment: Can't you take some time and format the question (capitalize, etc.) properly?

Comment: If $F$ is a field and $d\in F$ and $z$ is an element (possibly from some extension field $E$ of $F$) such that $z^2=d$, then $\{a+bz\mid a,b\in F\}$, often denoted $F[\sqrt{-d}]$ but I wasn't sure what you mean by that, is a field by the subfield criterion. I don't know what you are talking about Euclidean domains. $F[\sqrt{-2}]$ is usually not a Euclidean domain. $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ happens to be but that's special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is always a field. Because you are just adjoining an algebraic (in your case) or transcendental element to F. $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ Is not a field because $\mathbf{Z}$ is not a field.

Comment: thanks hamid enki